# Python Android - SMS function not work - Dual Sim Device

Tags: android, python, sms, qpython

i am trying to get sms message in my dual sim android device but result always null pointer exception

```
import androidhelper
droid = androidhelper.Android()
SMSmsgs = droid.smsGetMessages(False, 'inbox').result 
for message in SMSmsgs:
   print 'From: '+message['address']+' > '+message['body']+'\n'
```

i have disable one sim card, but the result remain same.

any advice for this problem??

Comment: dual sim has not been implemented yet. you can try sl4a : `import sl4a` and it uses the default sim.